# Changing views in a view Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

So I want to make an app like 7 min workout, so during the workout the view changes to a different exercise which usually consists of an image, a timer and a label which displays the exercise name. This all happens automatically so an example is,

View 1. an image is shown of a person doing a push up, a timer of 30 seconds is displayed, a title called table. After 30 seconds it transitions to a new view.
View 2. Same as above but different pictures and titles
View 3..... and so on.

I dont think its necessary to make different view controllers for all the exercises, so do you guys have any suggestions on what I need to do to make something like this.

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html

Comment: you are correct you don't need to take more than 1 view controller. In your current view controller just take a view(on this add your image and title) after 30 seconds fadeout this view and again fadein with new inputs to it.If you need a sample let me know

Comment: @CharanGiri  do you mean change the text and image after 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes, So that you will use less memory and can reuse the elements with out allocating it again

Comment: @CharanGiri, could you give me a code snippet of what you mean, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
UIView *baseView;
UILabel *titleLabel;
UIImageView *viewforPic;
float fadeDuration;
NSMutableArray *infoArray ;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSArray *imagesArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"red.png",@"blue.png",@"yellow.png",  nil];
NSArray *titleArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"red",@"blue",@"yellow", nil];

infoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<imagesArray.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:imagesArray[i] forKey:@"images"];
    [dict setObject:titleArray[i] forKey:@"titles"];
    [infoArray addObject:dict];
  //  [dict removeObjectsForKeys:keys];
}
NSLog(@"%@",infoArray);

baseView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 380)];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
titleLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[baseView addSubview:titleLabel];
viewforPic =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 320)];
[baseView addSubview:viewforPic];

[self showAnimationwithinfor:0];

}

-(void)showAnimationwithinfor :(int)tempIndex
{
titleLabel.text=[infoArray[tempIndex] objectForKey:@"titles"];
viewforPic.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];  //[temp[0] objectForKey:@"images"];

[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
    baseView.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f animations:^{
        baseView.alpha = 0.0f;
        if (infoArray.count>tempIndex+1) {
         int tempedIndex=tempIndex+1;
            [self showAnimationwithinfor:tempedIndex];
        }
    }];
}];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to change the view.you can also work on the same view. suppose your 30 sec work is done you can create new activity in the same view also. and if you want to move to the new View the then you can pass the data from one view to the different view. and to open new view one of the  code is

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View animated:YES];
```